# Is there something like conditional comments for blackberry to validate specific meta tags in a web app?

Tags: html, validation, web-applications, blackberry, meta-tags

I'm trying to pass w3 validation...

For `mobileIE` I can use conditional comments to "hide" meta tags like so:

```
<!--[if IEMobile]>
<meta http-equiv="cleartype" content="on">
<meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="false" />
<![endif]-->
```

my problem is meta for blackberry, for example:

```
<meta http-equiv="x-rim-auto-match" content="none" />
```

which forces numbers to be numbers and prevents BB from converting them into phone numbers.

**Question**:
Is there a validator proof way of adding these meta tags? Right now they are not passing. Is there a way at all to have them pass?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **HTML5**, you can only use `name` and `http-equiv` values that are *a)* defined in the HTML5 specification or *b)* registered in the WHATWG wiki. You can register new values in the wiki.

- `name` values: [defined in spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-meta-element.html#standard-metadata-names) | [registered in WHATWG wiki](http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/MetaExtensions) | [registration info](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-meta-element.html#other-metadata-names)
- `http-equiv` values: [defined in spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-meta-element.html#pragma-directives) | [registered in WHATWG wiki](http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/PragmaExtensions) | [registration info](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-meta-element.html#other-pragma-directives)